# If else statements with flags c++

Tags: c++, arrays, queue

So, I have this method to check if my queue array is decreasing, the problem when I check is that if the two first terms are decreasing, it says that the whole queue is decreasing but I want it to go over each member of the whole array.
Decreasing means that each integer is superior to the next one, until the end of the queue. Are my if, else statements wrong?
If it is decreasing, my boolean should return true, otherwise it should return false:

```
  template<class T>
bool queue<T>::isDecreasing() const {

    bool flag=false;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < _capacity; i++) {
        if(elements[i]>elements[i+1]){
            flag = true;
            return flag;

        }else if(elements[i]<=elements[i+1]){
            flag=false;
            return flag;
        }
    }
     return flag;
   }
```

Comment: Do you know what the `return` statement means?

Comment: it means return the value right ?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I sure hope that your array `elements` have at least `_capacity+1` number of elements in it.

Comment: use `_capacity-1` instead of `_capacity` you only need the final return statement when your condition is met also you need to break out of the loop as soon as you change the value of your `flag` variable

Comment: okay i get it thank you!

Comment: @Simo: Then why do you want to return a value in the **first** round of your loop if you actually want to examine the entire range?

Comment: Your entire function is equivalent to `return _capacity > 0 && elements[0] > elements[1];`. Exercise: figure out why that is.

Answer (score 1):

Start with `flag` set to `true`. Then in each iteration check if your assumption of array being sorted in descending order is incorrect using `if` statement. If it incorrect, set to flag to false and break the loop.
Also, the loop should run `n-1` times(n is the number of elements) because in each iteration you are accessing the value of current and the next element. so, in `n-1`th iteration, you will access the value of second last and last element.

```
template<class T>
bool queue<T>::isDecreasing() const {

bool flag=true;

for (size_t i = 0; i < _capacity - 1; i++) {
    if(elements[i]<=elements[i+1]){
        flag=false;
        break;
    }
}
 return flag;
```

}

Comment: this was very helpful

Comment: Glad I could help